# Как отследить поведение на пользователя на сайте?

Tags: javascript, python, frontend, flask

Мне нужно чтобы когда человек вышел с моего сайта, который сделан на Flask( python ), удалить фотографии из бд. Могу ли я сделать это на python? Если да напишите пж как, если нет, то напишите пж на каком языке это возможно и прикрепите пжлста код или ссылки на статьи.

Comment: "могу ли я сделать это на python?" да, конечно можете, сайт же на Flask

Comment: У вас же есть обработчик, который запускается при выходе пользователя. Так добавьте туда нужную логику.

Comment: Извините я новичок во всем этом, что за обработчик? Где он находится?Как мне узнать вышел ли пользователь со страницы или нет?( закрытие вкладки )

Comment: Обработчик закрытия страницы придётся писать на JS, если я не ошибаюсь. Почитайте про события `beforeunload` и `unload`: https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то понадобится

```
window.onload = function(){
        let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("take");
        let dict = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            dict[String(elems[i].src)] = elems[i].tagName;
        }
        let json = JSON.stringify(dict);
        console.log(json)
        fetch('/delete',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: json
        })
    }
```